# cocoa webview: searchFor:direction:caseSensitive:

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

**Bit of code:**

In my window. Is called when user presses enter inside the NSTextField.

```
- (IBAction)searchInArticle:(id)sender
{
    ResultTabView *tab = (ResultTabView*) [self.tabBar selectedTabViewItem];
    [tab searchForString:self.searchInArticleField.stringValue];
}
```

In my webview class:

```
- (void) searchForString:(NSString*)string
{
    [self.webView searchFor:string direction:YES caseSensitive:NO wrap:YES];
}
```

**Problem:**

I'am using searchFor:direction:caseSensitive:wrap: to search inside my webview. I have create a textfield where the user can input hes search term - it works fine for the first search, but the webview becomes firstresponder when the search is performed, and then my textfield is deselected.

That is actually okay but when i search again, the search does not find the next word. It keeps finding the first found word. I guess it's because the webview loses firstResponder when i click the textfield and that makes the selection inside the webview go away.

What can i do ? Any other ways to search a cocoa webview?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, textfield should be made first responder after the search.